# Loss for classification using MNIST data stays around the same through every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('mnist_train.csv')
X = data.drop('label', axis=1).values
y = data['label'].values
with tf.Session() as sess:
    Y = tf.one_hot(y, 10).eval()
hidden  = [5, 4, 3]

def costa(y, yhat):
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=yhat, labels=y)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)
    return loss

def train(cost):
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(cost)
    return train_op

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((784, hidden[0])))
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((hidden[0], hidden[1])))
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((hidden[1], hidden[2])))
    wo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((hidden[2], 10)))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, hidden[0])))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, hidden[1])))
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, hidden[2])))
    bo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, 10)))
    layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X1, w1) + b1)
    layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer1, w2) + b2)
    layer3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer2, w3) + b3)
    layerout = (tf.matmul(layer3, wo) + bo)
    yhat = layerout
    cost = costa(y1, yhat)
    train_op = train(cost)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    for epoch in range(1000):

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init_op)
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X1:X, y1:Y})
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X1:X, y1:Y})
            print("Loss for epoch {}: {}".format(epoch, loss))
```

The loss stays around the same, jumps up and down a lot, but does not decrease accordingly.

I can't seem to find what is going wrong here, any help would be appeciated.

Is it the activations to the layers or am I getting the cost function wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialising weights with a standard deviation of `(2.0/neurons_in_prev_layer)**0.5` worked like a charm for me! 
Also changed the hidden layers to, 2 hidden layers of 256, 256 neurons.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You are running `sess.run(init_op)` every epoch. This means that the model parameters are being reset to random numbers every epoch, and therefore will be unable to learn. Try putting this op before `for epoch in range(1000)`
2. You are creating a new session every epoch. Change your code so it looks like this:

   ```
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(init_op)

       for epoch in range(1000):
           sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X1:X, y1:Y})
           loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X1:X, y1:Y})
           print("Loss for epoch {}: {}".format(epoch, loss))
   ```

Comment: I did rectify that, yeah, but still the cost remains exactly constant now!

Comment: Maybe try a much higher learning rate to see if that helps get things moving. Also maybe try another method of initialising the variables like `glorot_uniform_initializer` - sampling from a normal distribution can create issues for a fully connected network.

Answer (score -1):

Okay one little tweak did the trick, I used RMSPropOptimizer instead and the loss started decreasing as expected.

I still have to figure out as to why this works, I’m still learning, but for now this is the solution I have.

Although the loss decreases very slowly.